# PHP MYSQL "merging" variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

IS it a way to merge a variable called "bob" in the table foo, with my variable bob2 in my table foo2?

so they match eachother all the times.

Since im updating "bob". i want if that value changes, it also does to bob2, and vise versa.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `player` varchar(12) default '',
  `rank` varchar(12) default '',
  `winpot` int(20) default '0',
  `gamesplayed` int(11) default '0',
  `tournamentsplayed` int(11) default '0',
  `tournamentswon` int(11) default '0',
  `handsplayed` int(11) default '0',
  `handswon` int(11) default '0',
  `bet` int(11) default '0',
  `checked` int(11) default '0',
  `called` varchar(11) default '0',
  `allin` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_pf` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_f` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_t` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_r` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
  FOREIGN KEY (winpot) REFERENCES brukere(hand)
);
```

error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (winpot) REFERENCES brukere(hand) )' at line 20
```

im trying to get winpot reference to hand in the table brukere.

What is wrong here?

edit2:

```
create table brukere(
  hand int(20) NOT NULL,
  id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `player` varchar(12) default '',
  `rank` varchar(12) default '',
  `winpot` int(20),
  `gamesplayed` int(11) default 0,
  `tournamentsplayed` int(11) default 0,
  `tournamentswon` int(11) default 0,
  `handsplayed` int(11) default 0,
  `handswon` int(11) default 0,
  `bet` int(11) default 0,
  `checked` int(11) default 0,
  `called` varchar(11) default '0',
  `allin` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_pf` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_f` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_t` varchar(11) default '0',
  `fold_r` int(11) default 0,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
FOREIGN KEY (winpot) REFERENCES brukere(hand)
);

Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_2_7249b.stats' (errno: 150):
```

( could not upload trought SQL ( still looking into that) . so posted it here. Hope you dont mind

what is wrong here?

Comment: You're most likely doing this wrong, look into foreign keys to do this kind of relation.

Comment: You're missing a comma after the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of relation is very common in sql, but you usually build it in a way that you don't have to update the second table, i.e., you use id's in each table to represent their values, and when change the variable values, you don't have to update multiple tables.

For example:

If you have a table foo

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
     id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and table bar

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
     id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     foo_id INTEGER NTO NULL,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(id)
);
```

This way, when you change the name of bob to john on table foo, you don't have to change anything on table bar, since you have the reference to the id field and not the name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! is this working from foo1 to foo too? or do i need to have that code in the table foo too? :P

anyway, will try this!

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `player` varchar(12) default '',
  `rank` varchar(12) default '',
  `winpot` int(20) default '0',
  `gamesplayed` int(11) default '0',
  `fold_r` int(11) default '0',
  FOREIGN KEY (winpot) REFERENCES brukere(hand)

  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
);


what is wrong?

Comment: You have some syntax errors and you have to create the table brukere first. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edd0e)

Comment: my hand is  hand bigint(255)

but still getting those errors.

Comment: i changed hand to bigint(255) [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71b307) and don't see the error. If you still have errors, put them on sqlfiddle and share it here

Comment: Does the hand has to be a primary key?

Comment: If you want to reference an ID from one table in another table, is good practice that it is a primary key. This ensures that it is unique.

Comment: Since i already have the table brukere and hand in my database , so making this stats table, and the winpot need to be the same as hand.

Comment: You should do this relation by id, not hand see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3add) on how you should create it. Then if you change Hand, you only change it in brukere, and the stats table is not changed, but it will reference the new hand (by id)

Comment: But in my brukere ( btw means accounts on english) im already using ID to something else.

and im using hand for a game with "money", there hand is the storage for it

Comment: It doesn't matter. Everything that needs information from the brukere table should be accesses through ID. When you want to get the information from stats, if you want to have the hand, you just do a join between the tables and select hand from brukere where brukere.id = stats.winpot

Comment: See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3add/2) for a small example. The tables have no records, but that's how you'd get the information of hand

Comment: In my mysql i get: #1005 - Can't create table 'mafia_game.stats' (errno: 150) (Detaljer...)


Do you have teamviewer of some sort? IF you could do this for me i could pay you a couple of $.

Comment: add your script to sqlfiddle and click build schema and then put the address here

Comment: I really dont find out how to post my script or upload it. when i click build schema i get error.

Comment: that's ok. if you get error on mysql, you will get error too on sqlfiddle. just post the address of that page here

Comment: I dont get any page up :| or i cant find out how to get the adress or upload it. ( in that code i included my brukere table.)

i uploaded it on pastebin now, since i could not get it with sqlfiddle. http://pastebin.com/BUNa9Qms

Comment: go to http://sqlfiddle.com, paste the script that is giving you errors on the left side and click build schema. Then, you copy the address of that page (it will look something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3add) and paste it here. I will be able to see it.

Comment: It wont let me build it since the error message is comming :/

anyway, in my prew comment i pasted a link to pastebin ( -.- )

Comment: See [here for the working script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cce43). The brukere.id and stats.winpot had different types. They have to match. Additionally changed the engine to InnoDB, since foreign keys do not work with the MyIsam storage engine.  Let me know if this works

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'mafia_game.stats' (errno: 150) (Detaljer...)

Comment: This has to have a different reason than the script that you are creating right now, since that script is running. You may want to check for other foreign keys, since that error is usually related to foreign keys. You can read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Do you have teamviewer?

Comment: Sorry, i don't. And i'm afraid i can't help you on this. You'll have to go through your tables and check for foreign keys associated with your brukere table. If you run into some specific problems, feel free to post another question. Regarding this one, if you feel this answer helped you, don't forget to accept it and maybe vote up.